# Cannot make ALFA AWUS036NHA network adapter active (Ubuntu 20.04LTS)

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, atheros

I've been having a look around to find how to make my ALFA AWUS036NHA network adapter my laptop's network interface but I haven't had much luck. I've tried installing the drivers, and I'm not sure if that's where I'm having the problem. My built-in wifi keeps dropping out so I thought I'd try an external one.

I will try to give all the relevant information, but as much as I use ubuntu quite often, I am by no means that fluent with linux so anything that I miss, please ask me to add it.

When I run `lsusb`, I get the output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

so I can see it is there at the second to last entry.

When I run `iwconfig`, I get the output:

```
wlx00c0ca993a0c  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

for the device in question. I'm not sure how to actually connect to anything with this. I have tried `ifconfig wlx00c0ca993a0c up` but this doesn't seem to do anything.

I then tried to install the drivers. First I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-ath9k-htc
reboot
```

Again, nothing happened and the default network card is still being used even after

```
sudo ifconifig wlp3s0 down
sudo ifconfig wlx00c0ca993a0c
```

The final thing I have tried is to install using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros
```

This then prompted me to add the keys, which I did. After this I ran the commands again and got the output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed
  firmware-atheros
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 27 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/873 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,803 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 204024 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-atheros_0.43_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-atheros (0.43) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/firmware-atheros_0.43_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/htc_7010.fw', which is also in package linux-firmware 1.187.27
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firmware-atheros_0.43_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

EDIT 1:
After running `sudo modprobe athk9_htc`, I get no output.

Running `sudo dmesg | grep ath` gives the output:

```
[    3.031592] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[    3.031718] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[    3.321557] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[    3.572001] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[    3.854140] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[    3.854144] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[    3.854146] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[    3.854147] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[    3.854148] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    3.854149] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[    3.854150] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[    3.854151] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[    3.863026] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca993a0c: renamed from wlan0
[  366.623494] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[  366.633781] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[  366.689730] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
[  538.754776] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[  539.038505] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[  539.290445] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[  539.556796] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[  539.556806] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[  539.556811] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[  539.556815] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  539.556818] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  539.556820] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  539.556823] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[  539.556825] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  539.573422] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca993a0c: renamed from wlan0
[ 1037.813810] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
[ 1059.511049] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[ 1059.795484] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[ 1060.047277] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[ 1060.315864] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[ 1060.315869] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[ 1060.315871] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[ 1060.315872] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 1060.315873] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 1060.315874] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 1060.315875] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[ 1060.315876] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 1060.331362] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca993a0c: renamed from wlan0
[ 4315.992158] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[ 4316.243814] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[ 6316.322040] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[ 6316.573622] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
```

Edit 2:

After following the advice of chili555's answer, I have run everything as in the answer and now when I run `sudo dmesg | grep ath`, I get the output:

```
[    3.031592] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[    3.031718] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[    3.321557] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[    3.572001] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[    3.854140] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[    3.854144] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[    3.854146] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[    3.854147] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[    3.854148] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    3.854149] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[    3.854150] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[    3.854151] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[    3.863026] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca993a0c: renamed from wlan0
[  366.623494] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[  366.633781] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[  366.689730] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
[  538.754776] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[  539.038505] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[  539.290445] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[  539.556796] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[  539.556806] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[  539.556811] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[  539.556815] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  539.556818] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  539.556820] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  539.556823] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[  539.556825] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  539.573422] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca993a0c: renamed from wlan0
[ 1037.813810] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
[ 1059.511049] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[ 1059.795484] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[ 1060.047277] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[ 1060.315864] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[ 1060.315869] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[ 1060.315871] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[ 1060.315872] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 1060.315873] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 1060.315874] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 1060.315875] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[ 1060.315876] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 1060.331362] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca993a0c: renamed from wlan0
[ 4315.992158] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[ 4316.243814] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[ 6316.322040] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[ 6316.573622] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[ 8634.988784] ath: phy3: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[ 8634.998794] ath: phy3: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[ 8635.255231] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
[10421.149380] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw requested
[10421.433865] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw, size: 51008
[10421.685730] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[10421.954366] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[10421.954374] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[10421.954378] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[10421.954381] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[10421.954383] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[10421.954385] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[10421.954387] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[10421.954389] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[10421.970537] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca993a0c: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe ath9k_htc` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep ath` I suspect a cfg80211 error. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "My built-in wifi keeps dropping out"  I'd look forward to your seperate question about this. I'd like to solve it.

Comment: @chili555 thank you, I have made an edit based on your comment. I will do some further research on why my built-in wifi keeps dropping out, and I will add this question soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice: "ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw" I suggest that you restore the original htc_9271-1.4.0.fw firmware:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware.
```

We also see: "ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code." I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and let us see a new output:

```
sudo dmesg | grep ath
```

**EDIT**: It still loads the incorrect firmware. Check:

```
ls /usr/lib/firmware/ath9k_htc
```

We hope that we only see:

```
htc_7010-1.4.0.fw  htc_9271-1.4.0.fw
```

We suspect that you also have, as dmesg indicates, htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw. If so, rename it so that it will not load:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/ath9k_htc
mv htc_9271-1.dev.0.fw htc_9271-1.dev.0.bak
```

Reboot.

Check the Network Manager icon. You should see "USB WiFi Not Connected." Can you click it and connect?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the details you asked for in this answer. Thank you again for the help

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: This has solved my problem, thank you.